# Airport passenger traffic dataset - worldwide

Tags: data-request, api

I am searching for an open database of airport traffic data. Ideally, the dataset would contain as many airports for as many countries as possible. Something like this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_airports_by_passenger_traffic_(2010%E2%80%932015)) but much larger.

Ideally, the data would be of a format similar to the above link:

|airport name| airport code| airport lat/lon| passengers in year X| passengers in year X-1| change in passengers traffic compared to previous year

Answer (score 1):

You can get data for all US airports here - but don't know about outside the U.S. https://www.faa.gov/airports/planning_capacity/passenger_allcargo_stats/passenger